# Arrow function in setTimeout doesn't set window as this

Tags: javascript, this

I have some method of an object assigned by a decorator (that's where the function f, and ms are taken from).

```
  function() {
        setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, arguments), ms); 
      };
```

'this' refers here to the object. But 'this' of setTimeout is window, not that object. If 'this' of an arrow function is taken lexically, then how come it's not taken from setTimeout? After all, in the following code:

```
let user = {
  firstName: "Ilya",
  sayHi() {
    let arrow = () => alert(this.firstName);
    arrow();
  }
};

user.sayHi(); // Ilya
```

'this' is taken from the function above. So if that function is setTimeout in the first situation why aren't both situations the same? I thought it might have had something to do with the function being passed as argument in one case, and in the other one as a local variable, but wouldn't this come down to the same in lexical environments?

**Why is there a difference?**

Besides, to test this out:

```
let obj = {name : "Jeff"};
let obj2 = {name : "Bart", fun2 : function(fun){fun();}};

obj.name2 = obj2.fun2(() => alert(this.name));
```

but now I don't get "Bart" alerted, but an empty string. When I replace "name" with length, I just get 0, the 'this' refers to the window.

**Why doesn't this work as intended?**

Comment: You have passed an arrow function as a callback function to `setTimeout`, so `this` inside this callback will refer to the `this` in the enclosing scope which is the method of the object. Functions use the scope in which they are defined, not the one in which they are called. Arrow function that you have passed to `setTimeout` is not defined inside the `setTimeout`.

Comment: "'this' refers here to the object. But 'this' of setTimeout is window", `this` was never set to any object whereas it was pointing to window object.

Comment: I meant that setTimeout is a method of window, so I thought that the arrow function would be declared inside of setTimeout, thus leading to setTimeout as the source of the value of 'this'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If 'this' of an arrow function is taken lexically, then how come it's not taken from setTimeout?

Lexical means that the scope is taken from where the function is declared, not where it is passed to.

Comment: But wouldn't the function just be declared inside of the setTimeout being executed?

Comment: It isn’t declared inside `setTimeout`. You aren’t looking at the source code of `setTimeout`. It is declared in the function expression that starts on line 1 of the first code block and then passed to `setTimeout` as an argument.

Comment: So does that mean that any arrow function passed as argument will not be declared as a local variable of the executing function, but rather before it?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I said.

Comment: is this also the case for function expressions?

Comment: Function expressions do not have a lexical `this`. Having a lexical `this` is the main point of an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
function f1() {
  return this;
}

// In a browser:
f1() === window; // true
```

In your function you have passed the `window` object to the setTimeout.

If you alter you function and pass just arguments you will get the object:

```
function f() {
  console.log(this);
};

function a (){
  setTimeout(() => f.apply([1]), 1000); // here this = [1]
}

a();  // Array [1]
```